# How to get the n-last digits of a number?

Tags: c, algorithm

I´m converting a Linux Logger to work in windows.
The logger prints with snprintf.
In linux, this logger output timeofday.tv_usec , that give something like this :

```
Jun 24 18:30:31-232928 test-transport...
```

In my windows version, using QueryPerformanceCounter, i generate results like this:

```
jun 24 23:54:18-866568508 test-transport....
```

In Linux, the uSeconds have exactly 6 digits, but this windows function generate 9 digits. How could i print only the 6 last digits ? Remember that this is a time critical code.

Comment: Printing the last 6 digits in the second example will give you `568508` and not `866568`, Are you sure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the remainder of dividing the number by 10 to the power of the number of digits you want to preserve.

In your case:

```
num % 1000000
```

Comment: Sure, how could i forget it ? I should sleep more !

Comment: Smart. Good idea there.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what the number `866568508` represents.  Is this nanoseconds?  Or microseconds?  Or is this in the units of some other number, such as `QueryPerformanceFrequency`?  So let's say `866568508` represents `866568508` ticks of an `n` Hertz clock.  Then, the amount of time in seconds represented by `866568508` is `866568508/n`.  This is `866568508*1e6/n` microseconds.

So, your idea of getting microseconds by using the last 6 digits is not necessarily correct.  Since you say you usually have 9 digits, n could be `1e9` (i.e., you have nanosecond resolution).  In this case, you can get microseconds from `866568508` by doing `866568508*1e6/1e9 =`866568508/1e3`.

But, as I said, all this depends upon you knowing what the resolution is.

From some quick google search, it seems like [`QueryPerformanceFrequency`](http://www.decompile.com/cpp/faq/windows_timer_api.htm) should give you the frequency.